# How to left align the cases in Latex?

Tags: equations, align, cases

I am using WinEdt. And trying to run the following code. However, the second item is coming in the middle. Can we align it to appear on the extreme left like the point (i)? Kindly help. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item Statement 1.
\item  \begin{equation}
X_r = \begin{cases}
          2r-2, & \text{for $k = 1$,}\\
          2r-3, & \text{otherwise}.
      \end{cases}
\end{equation}          
\end{enumerate}
```

I got the following ouptut after running the above tex code.

[image]

Comment: Does this equation have to  be numbered?

Comment: @Bernard My code gave numbered equation of which I could not screenshot properly. No, it is not necessary to be a numbered equation.

Comment: In this case, just do as advised by @JouleV.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. Yeah it is working.

Comment: BTW, it's not `cases` causing the centering.  It's the fact that you're in the `equation` environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try in-line math instead. Note: this will not number your `cases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item Statement 1.
\item $X_r = \begin{cases}
 2r-2, & \text{for $k = 1$,}\\
 2r-3, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$        
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative for `JouleV` solution would be to use `flalign` from `amsmath` as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item Statement 1.
\item \begin{flalign}X_r& = \begin{cases}
 2r-2, & \text{for $k = 1$,}\\
 2r-3, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}&\end{flalign}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: This leaves some very ugly vertical spacing, though.

Comment: @Peiffap Because this new environment will introduce vertical spacing for the sake of alignment itself.

Comment: I never said it was a problem with your code, I'm just pointing out that visually this answer is not the most pleasing, to me at least.

Comment: @Peiffap I understood that you did not tell that you had a problem with my code. However, I just wanted to give you an explanation for this occurence :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define generally a left align of the math mode using fleqn in your documentclass as a option.

Afterwards you need to \setlength\mathindent{0pt}